# Upgrade Google OAuth 1.0 token to OAuth2

Tags: google-oauth

Is there any way to upgrade the Google Oauth token and secret obtained using OAuth 1.0 to OAuth2 access token?

My application is having around 800+ Google users and if each user needs to go through the whole OAuth process again, it will be painful for them.

Haven't seen any posts regarding this anywhere.
Any help would be much appreciated as I have already moved my app to OAuth2 and need a way out for these users asap.

Answer (score 5):

Recently Google implemented a migration path for developers to migrate OAuth1 grants into OAuth2 ones. Check out [Google's documentation for the migration](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: This is no longer true, see Miguel Andres' answer**

Nope, they're two totally different systems, so there's no way of exchanging an OAuth 1.0 credential for an OAuth 2.0 credential.

With a little work you could make it so that new users go through the OAuth 2.0 flow and use an OAuth 2.0 credential, and slowly start migrating older users through to use 2.0 in batches.

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, Google does provide a way to exchange OAuth1 tokens by OAuth2 tokens.